# Getting the value from a button

Tags: swift

I've got a series of buttons that all contain randomly generated letters (ie. Button one is Z, button 2 is X... and so on). When the user tap on a button, I want to grab the value of that button and create a new label with that value.

This is the code I have now

```
@IBAction func zeroB(sender : UIButton) {
    buttonPress(sender) // highlight the button
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50))
    label.text = "\(sender.currentTitle))"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(26)
    letterView.addSubview(label)
}
```

It creates a label, but the text in the label displays as  `Optional("Z"))`.

What am I missing?

I should add that i'm completely new to iOS programming. I'm making an app to teach myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `currentTitle` of a `UIButton` is an optional string, you would be getting the `Optional(...)` part.

If you know that the title has been set to a non-`nil` string, use exclamation point to unwrap it:

```
label.text = "\(sender.currentTitle!))"
```

This will produce `Z)` in the label (I am assuming that the extra closing parenthesis is *not* a typo, and you actually want it in the title of your label). If you do not want the extra parentheses after the title, use

```
label.text = sender.currentTitle!
```

Comment: Thanks. y'know, I could have sworn I tried that. Long night.

Answer (score 3):

current Title is an optional. You can extract the optional in one of two ways:

1)

```
let labelText =  sender.currentTitle!
label.text = labelText
```

or 2)

```
if let labelText = sender.currentTitle {
    label.text = labelText
}
```